# How can I turn off flycheck minor mode for given directory

Tags: flycheck, directory-local-variables

So my question is like in title. I want to turn off flycheck minor mode for all files in directory.
I have specified in my .emacs file that it should be on in c++-mode, c-mode and few others, but I don't want this rule to apply to one given directory.

 Preferably I'd like to turn it off using .dir-locals.el file.
My knowledge of lisp code is very limited and since specyfying
 `(remove-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)` hasn't done anything, I don't really know what should I do to get the effect I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you wouldn't want to remove the hook, as that's a global effect.

You can disable the mode on a per-buffer basis, though. Use the `eval` pseudo-variable. e.g. a `.dir-locals.el` like this would act for any/all major modes:

```el
((nil . ((eval . (flycheck-mode 0)))))
```

Local variables are processed after mode hooks, so this should reliably counteract your existing code (n.b. I've not tested this).

Comment: Sadly this didn't do a trick for me. I found partial solution though with `((c++-mode (flycheck-disabled-checkers c/c++-clang c/c++-gcc)))` so that will do for now.

Comment: Curious. I don't use flycheck, but I just tested my approach with `linum-mode`, and it works as expected for me (in Emacs 24.5). Perhaps `flycheck-mode` is non-standard in how you disable it? (although that seems unlikely).

Comment: Now tested with flycheck too, which is also working as expected with your hook and my .dir-locals.el file.

Comment: When I put your code, and only your code, it worked, so I'm guessing it's because I don't really understand how elisp works and rest of my code was causing the problems.
I was putting it like this,
`((c++-mode
  (irony-additional-clang-options "libs")
  (company-clang-arguments "libs")))
((nil . ((eval . (flycheck-mode 0)))))`

Comment: And it's working. I'm really not sure what was malfunctioning. And why. All I can say is thank you for helping ;]

Comment: Be careful about your .dir-locals.el syntax -- it's quite easy to get it wrong. There's also plenty of potential for confusion caused by the differences between (but equivalence of) the dotted and non-dotted notation. I prefer to consistently use the more verbose dotted notation for dir-locals, but at the moment you'll have a combination of the two, judging by your previous comment. See `C-h i g (emacs) Directory Variables` and also `C-h i g (elisp) Dotted Pair Notation`. If you can grok the latter, you'll acquire some useful insights into list structures in lisp :)